# Does Finnair pay compensation when bags are delayed?

Tags: luggage, delays, finnair

On a recent Finnair flight from Germany to Tampere, Finnland, my checked in baggage was delayed. It arrived the same night but by that time I had already spent money on clothes and toiletries (approx. 80 Euros) since there was no information when my suitcase would arrive. AFAIK this isn't a case where they have to pay compensation (which would be denied boarding or severe delay under EU rules or bag irretrievably lost under international airline rules).

I am considering writing to Finnair to claim compensation. However, I'd like to avoid spending a whole hour scanning the receipts and filling in an online form only to find they would not reimburse me. My goal is to get cash, not miles are anything I need to spend with the airline.

How likely am I to receive compensation?

Comment: Do you want them to compensate the 80 Euros (which they might be obligated to) or are you looking for a bigger compensation?

Comment: Mainly the 80 Euros, though I'll take anything I can ;)

Comment: Just how many hours was it delayed?

Answer (score 1):

> [**Your Europe Air Passenger Rights**](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm)
>
> **Lost, damaged or delayed luggage**
>
> **Checked-in luggage**
>   If your checked-in luggage is lost, damaged or delayed, the airline is liable and you're entitled to compensation up to an amount of approximately EUR 1 300. However if the damage was caused by an inherent defect in the baggage itself, you're not entitled to any compensation.
>
> **Travel insurance**
>   To ensure you have sufficient coverage when travelling with expensive items it's advisable to take out private insurance. If you do not wish to do so you can for a fee request a higher compensation limit (in excess of EUR 1 300) from the airline you are travelling with. This must be done in advance and at the latest when you check-in.
>
> **Hand luggage**
>   If your hand luggage is damaged the airline is liable if it was responsible for the damage.
>
> **How to complain**
>   If you want to file a claim for lost or damaged luggage, you should do it in writing to the airline within 7 days, or within 21 days of receiving your luggage if it was delayed. There is no standard EU-wide form.